# Can't figure out how to check if anything has been inputted

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Alright guys so I'm learning C++ using Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ book, and one of the drills asks me to

Step one: Enter a number followed by a unit(allow cm, m, in, and ft)

Step two: Convert that number into meters and output it

Step three: Reject any unit that the program doesn't know how to convert

Step four: Reject any values without units

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin>>ch; }

int main()
{
    constexpr double cm_to_m = 100;
    constexpr double cm_to_in = 2.54;
    constexpr double in_to_ft = 12;

    double i, in_meters;
    string unit;

    while (cin >> i)
    {
        cin >> unit;
        if(unit == "cm" || unit == " cm") {in_meters = i / cm_to_m; cout << "That is " << in_meters << "m" << endl;}
        else if(unit == "in" || unit == " in") {in_meters = i * cm_to_in / cm_to_m; cout << "That is " << in_meters << "m" << endl;}
        else if(unit == "ft" || unit == " ft") {in_meters = (i * in_to_ft) * cm_to_in / cm_to_m; cout << "That is " << in_meters << "m" << endl;}
        else if(unit == "m" || unit == " m") {cout << "That is " << i << "m" << endl;}
        else if() cout << "You need to enter a unit after the number(cm, m, in, ft)" << endl;
        else cout << "I don't know that unit" << endl;
    }
}
```

My problem is at step four. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to check if no unit has been entered after the number. I've tried if(unit == " "), and everything similar to that, but when I just type in a number, it continues until I type in a unit.

If you guys can help with just giving hints so I can figure it out myself, that would be helpful :)

TIA

Comment: How about checking the stream state after entering a unit? (in general you should check inputs after attempting to read input and before using the result anyway)

Comment: Dietmar Kühl could you be a little more specific? How do I check the stream state after entering a unit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could wait till there is a \n(end of line) and check if there is no unit

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should *always* check whether input is successful *after* an attempt to read it. To do so, you'd check the stream state. Typically, that's done in combination with the read, e.g.:

```
if (std::cin >> unit) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // deal with no input being received
}
```

From the looks of it you want to constrain where the unit is located relative to the previous value: it seems you want the unit to be directly adjacent to the value or separated with at most one space. The input operator for `std::string`, like all well-behaved input operators, starts with skipping leading whitespace by default. If you don't want to allow arbitrary whitespace, you'll need to test for that explicitly.

When you want to allow at most one space character, you would need to deal with that explicitly. To do so you'd `peek()` at the next character and if it is a space (`' '`) you'd `ignore()` it. Next you can either disable skipping of leading whitespace using `std::noskipws` or `peek()` at the next character and fail if it is a whitespace character (`std::isspace()`). The next step would be reading the `unit`.

That is, reading the unit immediately after the value *could* look like this:

```
if (std::cin.peek() == ' ') {
    std::cin.ignore();
}
if (std:cin >> std::noskipws >> unit >> std::skipws) {
    // see if unit is a valid unit
}
else {
    // no unit was entered where expected
}
```

The `unit` variable won't include a space character unless you read the string differently, e.g., using `std::getline()`. Thus, you can simply check the `unit` against `"cm"`, `"in"`, etc. There is no point to check it against `" cm"` for example as this test will always fail.

In addition I'd also get rid of the `if ()` in your code: it serves no purpose other than adding confusion. I'm not even sure whether it is legal. [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) both refuse to compile code containing an `if`-statement with an empty condition.

Finally, instead of `keep_window_open()` I'd just wait for some input using `std::cin.ignore();`. If you insist in keeping this function, its implementation could still be simplified to become `std::cin.ignore();`.